# How do I write a form equivalent to this curl to send requests to my scrapyd instance?

Tags: curl, scrapy, scrapyd

```
curl http://localhost:6800/addversion.json -F project=firstproject -F version=r2 -F egg=@/tmp/scrapydeploy-ffa46x/project-1.0-py2.7.egg
```

Response:

```
{"status": "ok", "project": "firstproject", "version": "r2", "spiders": 2}
```

I have tried

```
<form action="http://localhost:6800/addversion.json" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="project" placeholder="project"></input>
    <input type="text" name="version" placeholder="version"></input>
    <input type="file"name="egg" placeholder="version"></input>
    <input type="submit"</input>
  </form>
```

With the same strings for the first two parameters as in the curl, and the same file selected for the third paramter.

reponse:

```
{"status": "error", "message": "ValueError: Unknown or corrupt egg"}
```

How do I make submitting this form behave exactly the same as the curl?

Comment: I am facing same issue if you have resolve please share with us thanks.